# Cucumber Java8: Why do I get "PendingException: TODO: implement me"?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

This is my first attempt to use the java 8 support to Cucumber.

So, I added

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

to my pom.xml.

Then for the step

```
Then REST Verify Azure LB rule FE port is 80
```

I first had an "old-style" step which worked fine:

```
@Then("^REST Verify Azure LB rule FE port is (\\d+)$")
public void validateLBFEPort(int port){
    azureResourceHandler.validateLBFEPort(port);
}
```

but when I tried to convert to java8 style (after commenting the old styled method, and implementing En interface of cucumber-java8):

```
public void ResourceGroupTestsImps(){

    Then("^REST Verify Azure LB rule FE port is (\\d+)$", (Integer port) -> {
        azureResourceHandler.validateLBFEPort(port);
    });
}
```

I started to get:

```
cucumber.api.PendingException: TODO: implement me
```

with the suggestion:

```
You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

Then("^REST Verify Azure LB rule FE port is (\\d+)$", (Integer arg1) -> {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
});
```

which is of course the same.

Why is that happening?

Comment: Move the java8 lambda style step definitions into the constructor instead of method.

Comment: @Grasshopper thanks. I did, and now I get: NullPointerException
 at cucumber.api.java8.En.Then(En.java:1370)
 at com.tests.resttests.azureTests.ResourceGroupTests.<init>(ResourceGroupTests.java:17)...  on the "Then" line

Comment: Lambda step definitions are not necessarily an upgrade over annotation based step definitions. The `cucumber-java8` name is unfortunate in that implies an upgrade.

Comment: @mpkorstanje It does spares the need of defining a method name... :)